# Project Euler #3 Java

Tags: java, numbers

```
public class Problem3 {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        System.out.print(primeMod(60085147514L));
    }

    public static double primeMod(long d) {
        long max = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for (long i = 2; i < d; i++) {
            if (d % i == 0) { 
                boolean isPrime = primeCounter(i);
                if(isPrime == true) { 
                    max = i;
                    System.out.println(max);
                }
            } else {
                max = max;
            }
        }

        return max;
    }

    public static boolean primeCounter(long x) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int s = 1; s <= x; s++) {
            if (x % s == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count == 2) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My program works for smaller numbers but it Throws an Arthmetic Exception  for Divide by 0 when its not dividing by  zero.please dont give me the answer,just wanna understand it and improve my skills
thank you

Comment: When you get an exception, please post the relevant portion of the stacktrace, and at least, the line on which the exception occurs.

Comment: i tried your program i aint getting no exception.

Comment: How do you know it's not dividing by zero? Please post some output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that `s` is overflowing, leading eventually to a divide by zero.  Make `s` a `long` instead.

Comment: This looks like the problem. I get the exception on the line `if(x%s == 0) {` which means that `s` is zero.

Comment: `for (int s = 1; s <= x; s++)` `x` is a `long`, `s` overflows indeed, since the number in question has divisors exceeding `int` range.

Comment: @Code-Guru how would s become zero when its initialized to 1 ?? and theres on s--.

Comment: @chaitanya10 Because `s` overflows the maximum value of `int`. Try adding a SOP to primeCounter() to see the values of `s` for yourself.