# Project Euler 3 Java ArithmeticException

Tags: java

This gets all the prime factors of the number but it keeps going and then outputs negative factors of the number for some reason, help? Link to the question here: http://projecteuler.net/problem=3

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long number = 600851475143l;

    divChecker(number);
}

public static void divChecker(long n) {
    int div = 2;
    while (div * div < n) {
        if (n % div == 0) {
            primeChecker(div);
            div++;
        } else {
            div++;
        }
    }
}

public static void primeChecker(long n) {
    int div = 2;
    while (div * div < n) {
        if (n % div != 0) {
            div++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (n % div != 0) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Output here:

```
71
839
1471
6857
-716151937
-408464633
-87625999
-10086647
-5753023
-1234169
-486847
-104441
-59569
-6857
-1471
-839
-71
-1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at Bucky.divChecker(Bucky.java:13)
    at Bucky.main(Bucky.java:7)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project Euler #3 Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611149/project-euler-3-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your multiplications with `int` are eventually overflowing, yielding the "negative" factors.

Declare your `div` variables as `long` instead of `int`.

```
long div = 2;  // Two places in the code
```

With that change, I get this output only, and Windows calculator verifies that their product is your original number to factor, `600851475143L`:

```
71
839
1471
6857
```